# How to make a day go 24 hours back given date and a time?

Tags: javascript, date, time, push-notification, localnotification

I'm new at notifications and as well as working with dates and time. I've tried finding things like mine but i can't find anything that changes the time and not just the date.

```
var eventTime = Event.date;
var _24_hours_before_event = new Date(eventTime - 86400000);

cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_VALUE) + 1,
    title: Event.title + "is in 24 hours",
    text: Event.description,
    at: _24_hours_before_event,
    data: {
        eventId: Event._id,
        time: 24
    }
});
```

As you can see I'm trying to send a user a notification, warning them that an event will be in 24 hours. Now the way it knows when to send the notification is the user puts in a time, saved in Event.date. Then, given that time, it will subtract 24 hours (That's the part i'm stuck on). Event.date would look something like this 2016-01-09T14:00:00.000Z. I tried doing something like this Date(eventTime - 86400000),but that didn't work. What i need help is how I can make this 2016-01-09T14:00:00.000Z go back a full day. Which should look like this 2016-01-08T14:00:00.000Z. Also, just to be clear, if the time is 5:00am Jan 6 2013 then i want the notification to show up at 5:00am Jan 5 2013. Thanks for your help.

**Solution**

I found out that 2016-01-08T14:00:00.000Z or Event.date is a string and not an integer. The way I made it an integer was doing `new Date(Event.date)` like so:

```
var eventTime = new Date(Event.date);
var _24_hours_before_event = new Date(eventTime.getTime() - 86400000);

cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
   id: Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_VALUE) + 1,
   title: Event.title + "is in 24 hours",
   text: Event.description,
   at: _24_hours_before_event,
   data: {
       eventId: Event._id,
       time: 24
   }
});
```

I also added .getTime() so 86400000 can get subtracted from the date given.

Comment: `but that didn't work` - in what way did it not work? 86400000ms is one day so your maths is right. Please expand on why you think this didn't work

Comment: When i mean "it didnt work" im talking about it didnt send the notification before the day. It didn't send it at all. @JaromandaX

Comment: so this code is run on a server of some sort

Comment: ... oh, wait `cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule` ... nevermind :p

Comment: can you confirm that `_24_hours_before_event` ends up being a valid Date object - if not, the problem could be with the format of `Event.date`

Comment: It just so happens `Event.date` was a string and not an integer. Thanks for your help @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0):

If you would use [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) you could set your `_24_hours_before_event` variable to the following:

```
moment(eventTime).subtract(1, 'days').toDate();
```

If you do a lot of date-handling it might be worth to consider.

You can check out the [full documentation here](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Comment: if anyone needs `momentjs` just to subtract 24 hours from a date object, they need to give up programming and take up basket weaving

Comment: I don't think you need to be rude.